# How to use C# to request a OAuth2 Bearer token and then send JSON payload to the REST API

Tags: c#, wpf, api, rest

A website need me to POST below request to get a Bearer token first. This token will expire every 30 minutes. How can I use C# to get the response content? I didn't install any 3rd party libraries in my VS2012.

The website REST API help says: POST below information to the endpoint. Your new token can be found under ‘authentication_token’ in the response.

```
{
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "client_secret": "sxxxx",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "use WPF" to do it. But for making HTTP requests in C#, take a look at the HttpClient class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0

Comment: I mean, just use C# to get the response. WPF is the method I build desktop tool.